# Efficiently/multithread run regression predict

Tags: r, parallel-foreach, mclapply

I know there are many posts about the issues with memory consumption of `mclapply` but still I'm trying to see whether there's anything that can help my case.

I'm fitting a random forest model to a ~600 by 60,000 (response y by variables matrix X) matrix:

```
library(randomForest)
fit <- randomForest(x=X,y=y)
```

I then want to compare that fit to a random fit and for that what I'm doing is:

```
library(parallel)
set.seed(1)
random.list <- mclapply(1:1000,function(f){
  idx <- shuffle(nrow(X))
  random.y <- predict(object=fit,newdata=X[idx,],type="response")
}, mc.cores = ncores)
```

Unfortunately this is too memory intensive (requires more than 100GB) which makes it impractical.

BTW the environment I'm running on is Linux.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `mclapply2 {snpEnrichment}` is a reasonable effortless solution